# Streaming .asx in Android

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer, asx

I've been trying to stream .asx file and it was not working and mediaplayer returns errors.

This is my code

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();  
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();  
                try {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.tamilatlas.com/tamilrmxs/dynasty/dynastychunez.asx");
                    mp.setDataSource(uri.toString());
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

mp.start();
```

I found following error in logcat

```
11-01 10:03:59.484: E/MediaPlayer(21233): error (1, -2147483648)
11-01 10:03:59.484: W/System.err(21233): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
11-01 10:03:59.488: W/System.err(21233):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
11-01 10:03:59.488: W/System.err(21233):    at com.mayuonline.streaming.StreamingActivity.onCreate(StreamingActivity.java:18)
11-01 10:03:59.488: W/System.err(21233):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-01 10:03:59.488: W/System.err(21233):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-01 10:03:59.488: W/System.err(21233):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-01 10:03:59.488: W/System.err(21233):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-01 10:03:59.488: W/System.err(21233):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-01 10:03:59.492: W/System.err(21233):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-01 10:03:59.492: W/System.err(21233):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-01 10:03:59.496: W/System.err(21233):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-01 10:03:59.496: W/System.err(21233):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 10:03:59.499: W/System.err(21233):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-01 10:03:59.499: W/System.err(21233):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-01 10:03:59.499: W/System.err(21233):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-01 10:03:59.499: W/System.err(21233):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-01 10:03:59.503: E/MediaPlayer(21233): start called in state 0
11-01 10:03:59.507: E/MediaPlayer(21233): error (-38, 0)
11-01 10:03:59.511: E/MediaPlayer(21233): Error (-38,0)
```

Thanks for your time. I've been searching in many place but there are no valid example for asx streaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to parse the .asx file, to find the links(s) to the real stream there.

Here's a link for the .asx file format, maybe that can give you some hints as to how you will parse it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Stream_Redirector

I can tell you that I succeded in parsing one .asx file with the `Scanner` class. I did not find any general solution though. But maybe this is enough to get you started.